Maintain and deploy environment specific Salesforce namedCredentials & metadata using Azure DevOps
We are using Azure DevOps to deploy code on multiple Salesforce orgs using Salesforce CLI project commands i.e., https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.246.0.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_project_commands_unified.htm). Most of the components are common for all orgs except for below environment specific ones:

customLabels - contains values for labels
namedCredentials - contains
API endpoints, and access credentials (i.e., username & password)
brandingSets - contains themes (i.e., headers, footers & login)

For customLabels, we have successfully implemented the solution by:

Created folder paths "force-app/main/default/labels/${SF_ENV}/CustomLabels.labels-meta.xml" in codebase, and developers put separate content based on respective sandboxes.
Using Azure DevOps script, we move respective environment specific "CustomLabels.labels-meta.xml" file to folder path "force-app/main/default/labels"
Delete ONLY folders under "force-app/main/default/labels", which will leave the custom label meta XML file
Deploy to salesforce using "sf project deploy start" CLI command

I am okay to implement the similar solution for brandingSets, but the challenge is for namedCredentials because it contains sensitive data i.e., URL and login credentials. Writing username & password in open text formal and saving in repository is a security concern. Through Azure DevOps, we are able to access secrets from AWS vault, but access to this vault is restricted ONLY to Azure DevOps.
Please could you provide any suggestions how to maintain sensitive credentials in repo and also deploy environment specific namedCredentials using DevOps?

Through Azure DevOps, we are able to access secrets from AWS vault, but access to this vault is restricted ONLY to Azure DevOps - problem solved, then.

Through Azure DevOps I can pull the secrets from AWS vault, then do you suggest me to recreate the meta XML file of namedCredentials by replacing the username, password and URL for each Salesforce environment?

Sure, that works.

@SambitSwain Can these named credentials be deployed as a manual step? Or at least can they be deployed with dummy credentials and then populated manually as a post deployment step?

@identigral okay, that would result in difference between code commit on repo and code deployed on sandbox. Isn't there a solution in Salesforce which can handle this, and file content manipulation can be ignored in DevOps?

@DevelBase2 this is how we are already doing it, and it requires manually updating URL & credentials in each Sandbox after every deployment. Our plan is to automate it, and map environment specific details in namedCredentials. I am not sure why Salesforce cannot store the credentials internally, and use the environment specific values?? That would avoid Azure DevOps to manipulate/recreate meta XML file during CI/CD process.

@Everyone, I received another solution to this scenario which looks more effective (i.e., more control to developers) - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_ws_string_replace.htm hope this helps!
